# How to sum all values in a column excluding string values in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, case

I have a table that I want to do a sum of two fields. However since there are different data types within a column it is causing an error when trying to sum values. **I am seeking a way to add all numeric values in a column excluding non-numeric values.**

**Here is my table:**

```
id | value | stock
1,    -    ,45
1,    30    ,45
2,    -    ,-
2,    30    ,-
2,    -    ,-
3,    400, 55
3,    400, 60
4,    404,  55
```

**here is what I want the output to look like:**

```
id | value_total | stock_total
1,      30,             45
2,     30,              -
3,     800,            115
4,     404,            45
```

**here is my code:**

```
    SELECT id, SUM(NVL(value_total,0)) AS volume_total, 
SUM(NVL(stock_total,0)) AS stock_total
FROM table1 
group by id
```

**I get this error:**

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

**My assumption is that the error is coming from the '-' values within the columns.** Any tips or suggestions to add all numeric values in field but exclude the '-' values?

Comment: First, I assume that your actual data doesn't have commas.  Second, why would the `stock_total` for `id` 1 be 45 rather than 90 given the sample data you posted?  There are 2 rows in the source table with an `id` of 1 and a `stock` of 45.  Third, why would you declare `stock` and `value` in the source table as, apparently, `varchar2` rather than `number`?  Using the proper data type will save you a world of pain.

Comment: @mail_the . . . Are you really using an unsupported version of Oracle?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`to_number()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_NUMBER.html#GUID-D4807212-AFD7-48A7-9AED-BEC3E8809866) with `on conversion error`:

```
SELECT id,
       SUM(TO_NUMBER(value_total DEFAULT 0 ON CONVERSION ERROR) AS volume_total, 
       SUM(TO_NUMBER(stock_total DEFAULT 0 ON CONVERSION ERROR) AS stock_total
FROM table1 
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: The question is tagged for Oracle 11g.  If that's actually the version being used, the `on conversion error` enhancements to `to_number` aren't available.  In more recent versions, this would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a `CASE` expression and `regexp_like()` to only pass strings that represent a number (in decimal notation) to `to_number()` and return a `0` otherwise. Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT sum(CASE
             WHEN regexp_like(value_total,
                              '^(\+|-)?[0-9]*((.)?[0-9])[0-9]*$') THEN
               to_number(value_total)
             ELSE
               0
           END) value_total
       FROM table1;
```

But ideally, you fix your schema and use an appropriate data type for the columns, namely some `number` variation.